# Russian equivalents of "We would never hear the end of it"

Tags: выражения

We were talking about ... My girlfriend whipped up a mousse-like cold dessert with some fresh fruits, but the thick slices of apple inside turned out a bit too frozen to eat as is. And here I wanted to jokingly say something along the lines of:

> If somebody cracked a tooth on one of those frozen solid apples, **we would never hear the end of it**!

- {In the sense of}: *We might as well still be hearing some complaint or other in ten years' time.*

Idiomatic Russian phrasings for this elude me. How is this idea commonly expressed in Russian?

Comment: @Abakan A year has passed and you're still having perverse fun in going around casting trolling votes, I see. Some people never change. Farewell.

Comment: I'll try to answer your question but couldn't you explain what "idiomatic" is? What is idiomatic among ourselves wouldn't be in use amid a company at a nearby table in a restaurant, for example. To say nothing about different social, regional, age brackets.

Comment: @Eugene Hi. The word "idiomatic" or "idiomatically" has nothing to do with "idioms" here. It means "natural-sounding to native speakers of a particular language".

Comment: I don't guarantee that native speakers will say this way but I'd proffer the following: "If somebody cracked a tooth on one of those frozen solid apples, он нам весь мозг выхорит/выдолбит/выклюет,  or ...он нас поедом съст/ поедом будет 10 лет есть, or ... он нам всю голову прохавает, or ... он нам до гробовой доски это вспоминать будет, and many other possibilities.

Comment: ..., то разговорам (или жалобам) конца не будет.

Comment: Они будут поминать нам до скончания века/// до гробовой доски/// Потом нам своими жалобами всю плешь проедят

Answer (score 10):

There's a fairly common phrase:
*кто-то* будет долго [нам] припоминать *что-то*
(*someone* will remember *something* for a long time;
literally: *someone* will remind [us] of *something* for a long time).

As an option,
*кто-то* будет до конца дней [нам] припоминать *что-то*"
(*someone* will remember *something* for the rest of the days;
literally: *someone* will remind [us] of *something* for the rest of the days).

However, this phrase in most cases is addressed to whoever's responsible for what happened (at least indirectly).

For example, if you accidentally (or not) break someone's car, they "будет долго это припоминать" (will remember this for a long time; literally: will remind you of this for a long time)". So, we can't say that they will *"долго это припоминать" to someone* who had nothing to do with what happened.

As far as I know, the word "припоминать" is more often found in fiction and spoken language. It is practically not used in official texts.

One more option is "эта песня никогда не закончится" (this song will never end) или "[это] бесконечная песня" (it's an endless song). These can mean both "they will never stop saying anything" and "they will never stop doing anything".

Upd: Perhaps, this expression would be more appropriate to your sentence:
"слушать об этом до конца жизни" (to listen about it for the rest of life),
"слушать об этом до конца дней своих" (to listen about it for the rest of (literally) one's days)":

Если кто-то сломает зуб об это заледеневшее яблоко, мы будем слушать об этом до конца жизни.

Upd2: I'm not sure that "слушать об этом" is grammatically correct in Russian.
But I asked a question to the helpdesk and will soon post their answer.
Btw, instead of "слушать об этом" you can say:

- "выслушивать это...". But it's usually about longer conversations. Not about those that are short and recurrent, as in our case.

Answer (score 7):

we would never hear the end of it!

Тебе это не раз припомнят. Тебе это всю жизнь будут припоминать. Этому конца-края не будет.Да он тебе всю плешь проест.Тебе этого никогда не забудут.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the most adequate translation is this:

"Ну, теперь это будет вечная тема."

Also, if you need to interrupt such a speaker here and now, you can say sarcastically:

"Ну давай, по десятому разу!"